# How to open my application in current state from notification

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

I need to open app in current state, without any new instance of my main Acitivity

Here is my code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(baseActivity, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("FROM_NOTIFICATION", true);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(baseActivity, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

and

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(baseActivity)
            .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon()).setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(baseActivity.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher))
            .setContentTitle(baseActivity.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(message)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

How can I do this? Or is there another way?

Comment: What do you mean by "without any new instance of my main Acitivity"? 

Where's the old instance? You mean it should not override the 'old' one if you're already in the app..?

Comment: @Vucko Yes. Is it posible?

Comment: Yes it is, I'm not beside my laptop at the moment to re-check what I'm using, but I think it was adding `android:noHistory="true"` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` in the `<activity>` that you want. If that does not work, I'll have to get back to you in 4h or so :D

Comment: do you got fixing this?

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan no(

Comment: @Vucko there is no such thing

Comment: you want to open the app instance when app is closed and to open the existing instance when you click on the notification . correct ?

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan Yeah! Did you know?

Comment: check my answer below !! if it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Try setting flag to the intent as below..

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

instead of

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

in your code.

Hope this helps you.
Let me know for queries.